# Can I have a bridged interface without an IP?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, bridge, lxc

I have 2 NICs: eth0 & eth1 on a host OS which runs some VMs (LXC) under it.

- The hosts **eth0** is connected to a private network and configured as the primary interface.
- The hosts **eth1** is connected to the DMZ.
- **Each VM has a static IP** that bridges to eth0 on the host.
- Some VMs, which need a public IP, have a 2nd virtual NIC bridged to the hosts eth1.

**Question:**

- Can I remove the IP address on the hosts eth1 NIC? The host has absolutely no need for a public IP address, I only need to bridge the interface to selected guest VMs. It's the guest VM which will host a service on whatever public IP its assigned.

Cursory attempts at removing the IP on the hosts eth1 have generated errors.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/445991/bridging-lxc-containers-to-host-eth0-so-they-can-have-a-public-ip).

Comment: Have generated what errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work, as long the interface is still up

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep UP
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

the bridge is a "switch" and it doesn't need to have one IP. But please check if you have firewall rules in eth0:

```
iptables -l -vnx
```

if rp_filter is off

```
 cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth1/rp_filter
 0
```

and if all fails, try to enable the STP:

```
 brctl stp br0 on
```

and enable the promisc mode in that interface:

```
  ifconfig eth0 promisc
```

(ifconfig eth0 -promisc to remove it)

Of course, also check if there is no other config using that removed IP :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works.

It depends on your operating system on how to configure such a network setup in a way that the bridge is up and running after a reboot in that constellation.

From my experience:

- SLES10 SP4: Works - do not use `yast2`
- SLES11 SP2: Works - use `mv` to rename the bridge to something useful after setup with `yast2`
- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS: Works only manually - Ubuntu keeps setting a dummy-IP.
- RedHat 5: Works - use `vi`.